# How did they light Magneto's plastic prison?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

Both versions of the plastic prison, but especially the Pentagon prison, were well lit. How did they do this without using metal in the wiring and lightbulbs?

Comment: Plastic and glass fibre-optics, probably. There's basically no limit to how far you can send a beam of light.

Comment: You might find this interesting; [Lighting circuit without metal](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/15240/9255)

Comment: Solar tubes perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_tube?wprov=sfti1 though I don’t have time to make it an answer.

Comment: @Longshanks - I'm pretty sure OP is looking for fact-based answers from the film (or any additional materials such as interviews) rather than educated guesswork about how you could move light around without metal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About the absence of metal in machinery and buildings of the past](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86996/about-the-absence-of-metal-in-machinery-and-buildings-of-the-past)